# Why can't I iterate over a ListProperty in AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've just got this error from Google App Engine:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'ListProperty' is not iterable
```

why?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, it's impossible to see what exactly you're doing wrong, but it looks like you're trying to iterate over the property itself - eg, SomeClass.my_list - rather than an instance - eg, an_instance.my_list.